# Entire Dimension Table is Rapidly Changing

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling, data-warehouse

The way our database is designed is everytime a customer purchases a product, all the attributes of the product are recorded in a new row (type 2 SCD). I know this sounds stupid but in reality it's not actually customers and products (just using that analogy to make things simpler) so the design is correct. I'm having trouble coming up with a data model design as the product dimension table would have to be as large as the fact table. I know there are mini dimensions but they are only applicable when a portion of the dimension table is rapidly changing. Are there any designs for when the entire dimension table is rapidly changing? I could just keep it a regular type 2 but it would blow up in size if the fact table is millions of rows and kill performance.

Comment: This doesn't make sense in modelling it. The product dimension should contain a distinct list of products. For a Type2 SCD is only makes sense to add a new row if an existing product will have changes, for example name of the item. It should not be as big as the fact table, or used to record transactions like you are describing. Dimensions are reference, I would relook at your design or post more info on it

Comment: If all the attributes are being assigned at the point of sale then this sounds more like a (possible factless) fact than a dimension. It would probably make more sense if you described the actual situation (possibly with sample data) rather than the customer/product dummy entities

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working with Power BI and must handle a rapidly changing dimension table. In that case, there are 4 major points you need consider to optimize performance and manage the data efficiently:

Instead of loading the entire dimension table each time, you can implement an incremental loading strategy in Power BI. This involves loading only the new or updated records from the dimension table into your Power BI dataset. I recommend reading about query folding, partitioning, or data connectors supporting incremental loading.

Power BI supports composite models, which allow you to combine data from different storage modes, such as importing data into Power BI's internal data model and connecting directly to a database. You can keep the slowly changing attributes in the imported data model for faster querying while connecting directly to the rapidly changing attributes from the source database.

If your dimension table is huge and contains detailed data not always needed for analysis, you can consider aggregating and summarizing the data in Power BI. This involves pre-calculating and storing summarized data at different levels of granularity, such as daily, weekly, or monthly. Using summarization techniques like data cubes, materialized views, or aggregations in Power BI can improve query performance and reduce the amount of data to be loaded.

Instead of importing the dimension table into Power BI, you can connect directly to the source database using DirectQuery or Live Connection. This way, Power BI can leverage the database's processing power and handle the updates and queries directly on the database side. It allows real-time access to the rapidly changing data, but you should consider the performance impact on the database.